# why the offsets.QuarterBegin date is 12-01, 03-01, 06-01, 09-01?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, offset

```
t = pd.Timestamp('2020-02-05')
print(pd.offsets.QuarterBegin().rollback(t))
print(pd.offsets.QuarterEnd().rollback(t))
```

out:

```
2019-12-01 00:00:00
2019-12-31 00:00:00
```

why the result is 2019-12-01? Shouldn't it be 2020-01-01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterBegin.html#pandas-tseries-offsets-quarterbegin) specify that there is a `startingMonth`; e.g. "*startingMonth = 3 corresponds to dates like 3/01/2007, 6/01/2007*". To find out what the default of this keyword argument is, you can have a look at the [src](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx) and observe that `_default_starting_month = 3` ([link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/31db14c489224e92fcc8729ad44a2ebb5114db22/pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx#L2130)).

So without providing `startingMonth`, your quarters start at month = 3, 6, 9, 12 - which is why you get `2019-12-01 00:00:00` if you "rollback" `pd.Timestamp('2020-02-05')`.

If you want your quarters to start e.g. on month = 1, 4, ... and end on month = 3, 6, ... (inclusive), you can set the keyword to 1 (and 3 respectively for QuarterEnd):

```
t = pd.Timestamp('2020-02-05')
print(pd.offsets.QuarterBegin(startingMonth=1).rollback(t))
print(pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(startingMonth=3).rollback(t))

2020-01-01 00:00:00
2019-12-31 00:00:00
```